# Can a function be differentiable at a jump discontinuity?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, self-learning

I learnt in spivak's calculus that if a function is differentiable at a point then it is continuous at that point however I am confused about this function for example
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
-2x & x<4, \\
8 & x=4. 
\end{cases}
$$
Is this function differentiable at $x=4$ since this point is an isolated point of the functions range the function is continuous at that point.
However why can we not calculate the derivative at $x=4$ the right hand limit need not exsist as the function is not even defined for values of x greater than 4 so why is the derivative not defined ?

Comment: $f$ is not continuous at 4.  Neither 4 is an isolated point of the **domain** of $f$.

Comment: How is it not an isolated point?

Comment: Any neighborhood of 4 contains other points of the domain, such as 3.99999999.

Comment: Just because $f$ was defined at $x = 4$ separately doesn't make $4$ an isolated point of the domain. Your domain is still $(-\infty, 4]$ and $4$ is not isolated. Every open interval $(a, b)$ containing $4$ intersects $(-\infty, 4]$ at, say, $(a + 4)/2 \neq 4$.

Comment: Try calculating the left hand derivative using the limit definition. You will see that it goes to infinity. In other words, the slope has to become vertical to accommodate the jump up to 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $f$ is not continuous at $4$, since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 4^{-}}f(x)=-8\neq f(4)$. Recall that $x\in D(f)$ is an isolated point of the domain if there exists $\delta> 0$ such that $[(x-\delta,x+\delta)\setminus \{x\}]\cap D(f)=\emptyset$. Check that this is not the case.

Now, differentiability $\Rightarrow$ continuity still holds for left-differentiability and left-continuity. As the function is not left-continuous, it cannot be left-differentiable at $x=4$.

Answer (score 3):

The (one-sided) derivative at $4$ would be

$$ \lim_{x\to 4} \frac{f(x) - f(4)}{x-4} = \lim_{x\to 4} \frac{-2x - 8}{x-4} = \lim_{x\to 4}\left(-2- \frac{16}{x-4} \right)$$

which doesn't exist. So $f$ is not differentiable at $4$, nor is it continuous at $4$: $$\lim_{x\to 4} f(x) = -8 \neq f(4).$$

In order to define a meaningful notion of "the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $a$" you need $a$ to be a limit/cluster point of the domain of $f$. So in particular if $a$ is an interior point then you can define the two-sided limit that you're used to. If $a$ isn't an interior point, but still a cluster point, then you can still talk about the limit as $x \to a$ but just be careful that some of the theorems you have seen might no longer apply if $a$ is not an interior point.

In this case, however, it is still true that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ (with $a$ a cluster point) then $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a question of definition. If you look at the definition of left-differentiability ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability), for instance), you will see that *according to that definition* your function is not left-differentiable at $x=4$. And that's that.

Comment: Sorry but why is the function not left differentiable at $x=4$

Comment: @Thehomeschooler: did you look at my link? There you will find a definition of left differentiability. Your function doesn't satisfy that definition.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to ask whether $f$ is continuous at 4 because differentiability is only defined for interior points of the domain, but 4 lies on the boundary.

Comment: can't we use one sided derivatives when talking about the derivative at an end point?

Comment: We can, but they're not the same as derivatives. Plus they don't generalise well to domains of dimension >1.

Comment: Defining differentiability at endpoints of intervals is a matter of taste at the introductory level. Some authors allow it, some don't. If you define differentiability as (the existence of) $\lim_{x \to x_0; x \in X - \{x_0\}}\frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0}$, as Tao does in his book, derivatives at endpoints automatically become one-sided.

Comment: @0XLR Does this notation imply x is within the domain of the function ?

Comment: I assume $X$ is supposed to be the domain of the function, therefore yes.